# Get property of an object

Tags: php, html, laravel, model

I have a one to many model. 
An WorkoutDetails which has many Exercises.

I was able to display all the data for the Exercises, but I need just the property 'Title'.

In controller I have

```
public function getDetails($id){

        $details = WorkoutDetails::where('parent_id','=',$id)->get();


        return View::make('menu_renderer.partials.details')->with('details', $details);
    }
```

And in HTML I have

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
        <div>
            <ul>
                {{$detail->exercises}}
            </ul>
        </div>
 @endforeach
```

And the output is:

> [{"id":1,"type_id":0,"title":"Exercise one","details":"Details
>   exercise one","media":"5","created_at":"-0001-11-30
>   00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
>   [{"id":2,"type_id":0,"title":"Exercise two","details":"Details
>   exercise two","media":"2","created_at":"-0001-11-30
>   00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
>   [{"id":3,"type_id":0,"title":"Exercise three","details":"Details
>   Exercise three","media":"6","created_at":"-0001-11-30
>   00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]
>   [{"id":4,"type_id":0,"title":"Exercise four","details":"Details
>   Exercise four","media":"6","created_at":"-0001-11-30
>   00:00:00","updated_at":"-0001-11-30 00:00:00"}]

Which is not bad, but I need just the title or details.

I tried

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
        <div>
            <ul>
                {{$detail->exercises->title}}
            </ul>
        </div>
 @endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
        <div>
            <ul>
                {{$detail->exercises.title}}
            </ul>
        </div>
 @endforeach
```

or

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
        <div>
            <ul>
                {{$detail->exercises[title]}}
            </ul>
        </div>
 @endforeach
```

But nothing...

Can anyone give me a hint how can I display just the title or details of each Exercise which belongs to WorkoutDetails model ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the dump provided, it seems another array is holding the inner data.

hence try :

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
        <div>
            <ul>
                {{$detail->exercises[0][title]}}
                // or : 
                {{$detail->exercises[0]->title}}
            </ul>
        </div>
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel query function `first()` to pickup the first object.

```
@foreach($details as $detail)
    <div>
        <ul>
            {{ $detail->exercises->first()->title }}
        </ul>
    </div>
@endforeach
```